# addObject to NSArray

Tags: xcode

I am a newbe and have been working all day readying/watching/searching for a solution to this. The following code works, but now how do I add an integer to the array?

```
    //this works

    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
        [NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.96], @"Hello World", nil]; 

   for (id obj in array)
    NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

The following returns error: Use of undeclared identifier 'obj'

```
    NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10],
       [NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.96], @"Hello World", nil]; 

    for (id obj in array) 
        [array addObject:7];
        NSLog(@"%@", obj);
```

Answer (score 6):

you must use a NSMutabbleArray not an NSArray to add objects dynamically and don't forget []  and arrayWithObjects is only for nsarray. try this:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10]];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:25.96]];
[array addObject:@"Hello World"];
[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];

for (id obj in array) {
    NSLog(@"%@", obj); 
}
```

Just Copy paste this code and it will initiate the array with object you want and then show them.

Comment: Oddly enough, the original mixed both string and numeric data and that seemed to work--don't know why that worked with a NSArray--but it seemed to work.  It's the appending of the original that I'm struggling with. I changed the arrays to NSMutableArray but still wouldn't allow the append.  The problem is in that addObject statement.

Comment: Just Copy paste the code above and it will initiate the array with objects you want and then show them.

Answer (score 3):

There are several issues here:

1. You are attempting to mutate (change) an immutable array.  You would need an `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray` to do what you want.  (Incidentally, your actual `NSArray` creation code is fine.)
2. Your `for()` loop is blowing up mainly because you don't have braces to delimit your code.  Absent braces, the compiler is going to use *only* the first line following the `for` as the loop contents.  Hence your `NSLog()` is outside the loop, and `obj` out of scope.
3. <strike>I don't know why you don't have brackets around your `addObject:` line, as in `[array addObject:...]`.  Did that even compile?  Is that a copy and paste error?</strike>
4. Finally, you can't add a naked integer to a Cocoa collection such as `NSArray`. You would need to follow what you properly did earlier in your code: `[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]]`.

Given that you were using indentation as syntax, I'm guessing maybe you have more of a Python (or similar) background?  If so, you are going to have to quickly adjust some of your modes of thinking to program effectively in C or Objective-C.  I *urge* you to get a beginners book on Cocoa programming and start at the beginning or you are going to get very frustrated very quickly.

Edit: I notice that after I posted you added brackets back in, so I struck #3 above.  This leads to another important note: make sure that if you ask a question that you copy and paste the **exact** code that failed. Never re-type!

Comment: Point well-taken on the re-type.

Comment: What beginners book on Cocoa would you recommend?

Comment: That's going to depend on whether you are more interested in iOS or OS X development.  I recommend anything from Aaron Hillegass and the Big Nerd Ranch crowd.  They have an ObjC book (http://www.amazon.com/Objective-C-Programming-Ranch-Guide-Guides/dp/0321706285) and books specific to each platform... see the "Customers Who Bought This Item Also Bought" link on Amazon.

Comment: Cool. Thanks!  I'm strictly interested in  writing ipad/iphone apps at this point.

Comment: I bought Aaron Hillegass's Objective-C Programming:The Big Nerd Ranch Guide.   It's great if your a newbie.  Between that book and watching a ton of tutorials, I've made great progress in a short period of time.

Comment: @dlcj Great! Glad it's working out for you! (Would you consider accepting my answer?)

Answer (score 1):

It's because your using indentation in your for loop which only considers the following line. Try this instead

```
     for (id obj in array) {
         [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:7]];
         NSLog(@"%@", obj); 
     }
```

**Note**

I think you need to use a NSMutableArray if you want to add objects after initialising it. Also it's not a good idea to modify a collection your looping through (in this case the loop will never end as you keep adding an object into an array your looping through). You can make a mutable version of the array by using this line.

```
NSMutableArray * mutArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
```

Comment: Wow. That was quick.  I corrected the indentation.  Still getting error, but this time the error is: Incompatible integer to pointer sending 'int' of type 'id'

Comment: Good point about the loop:  yea, not a good idea as a rule.  However, ultimately it will be adapted to allow user input. The loop was for me to see what it was doing.